# Greenplum add a column to table and insert value to it in incremental order

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment, greenplum

I have a table st.student like following, which has one column.

| STUDENT_ID |
| --- |
| 100001 |
| 100002 |
| 100003 |
| 100004 |
| 100005 |
| 100006 |

I need to insert a column to this and values in it should be incremental one. Like the following. Note that NEW_STUDENT_ID can start from any value. Once it starts, it's continuous. What's the query for this ?

| STUDENT_ID | NEW_STUDENT_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 100001 | 349009 |
| 100002 | 349010 |
| 100003 | 349011 |
| 100004 | 349012 |
| 100005 | 349013 |
| 100006 | 349014 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is altering the table using:

```
alter table student add column NEW_STUDENT_ID   serial;
```

Result:

```
student_id  new_student_id
100001          1
100002          2
100003          3
100004          4
100005          5
100006          6
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a5ac169d1f0304be1829d4b0e7d49873)

Another way, create a sequence with custom start and alter the table with using the created sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE new_student_id START 349009;

alter table  student add column   new_student_id int DEFAULT  nextval('new_student_id') NOT NULL;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c3106f36917c293005b5019da9bbb3a3)

[Reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html)